# How can i use Jquery Ajax post with htaccess

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, .htaccess

I try to post data with jquery. If i dont use htaccess Ajax code works. But when i use .htaccess, it avoid ajax post.

.htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

My ajax code in **/content?cid=98**

```
 $.ajax({  
                     url:"./Modal/contentModal.php",
                     method:"POST",  
                     data:{ noteArea:note, noteId: note_id, contentId:content_id },  
                     dataType:"text",  
                     success:function(data)  
                     {  
                          if(data != '')  
                          {  
                             $('#note_id').val(data);


                          }  
                          $('#autoSave').text("Post save as saved");
                          setInterval(function(){  
                               $('#autoSave').text('');  
                          }, 5000);  

                     }  
                });
```

Chrome console message

> jquery.js:8630 XHR finished loading: GET "http://109.232.216.239/~compuni/Modal/contentModal"

I also tried url: url:"./Modal/contentModal" The problem was not solved.
Thank You.

Comment: Did you check the network tab of dev tools to see what is being returned (ie 500,404 messages)? Did you check server logs to make sure your htaccess is not causing a 500 error? Have you tried adding a error callback to see what that returns

Comment: The URL is caught by the 301 rule. Is that what you want? Also, test your URLs by entering them in the browser first. Adding AJAX into the debugging mix is not a good idea.

Comment: @PatrickEvans there is no 500 or 404 message. There 301 moved permanetly (contentModal.php) and 200 OK (contentModal)

Chris, I'm not so perfect with software, Can you explain What i do 

Thank you

Comment: i deleted .htaccess file and add everywhere .php then i tried again. So it is not working again. After i try with localhost, data was sent by ajax. I dont know how i can solve the problem.